# Django GAE testapp tutorial

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm running Windows 10 (sorry) and I'm trying to set up the django-nonrel test app for GAE from github, https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-testapp.

I've downloaded and installed it and I've also installed the various modules from [Django and NoSQL](https://github.com/django-nonrel) on github.

So my filestructure is dbindexer, django, djangoappengine and djangotoolbox as subdirectories of testapp.  I've put these in place as I've come across install errors in the log file.

I'm now getting the message

> ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module autoload.middleware: "No
>   module named autoload.middleware"

This is reasonable since settings.py has autoload as an installed app.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'djangotoolbox',
        'autoload',
        'dbindexer',

        # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
        'djangoappengine',

)
```

But I don't know where I find this module.  I know I must be being really thick but I cannot work out how to get this running.

EDIT - here is the requirements.txt file

```
-e git+http://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox@toolbox-1.4#egg=djangotoolbox
-e git+http://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine@appengine-1.4#egg=djangoappengine
-e git+http://github.com/django-nonrel/django-dbindexer@dbindexer-1.4#egg=django-dbindexer
-e git+http://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.4#egg=django-nonrel
-e hg+http://bitbucket.org/twanschik/django-autoload#egg=django-autoload
```

So I've downloaded this autoload and I'm now getting the following error.

> ImportError: No module named fcntl

Comment: can you show your requirements.txt file ? It looks like you are installing the wrong autoload module

Comment: have you pip install -r requirements.txt? as you should not need to download modules manually, ideally. Just install them with pip via requirements.txt.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I wouldn't recommend django-nonrel for App Engine since it's a badly out-of-date fork. For one thing, Django will work better with a SQL database, you can use CloudSQL like in this example https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/appengine-django-skeleton. If you really want to, use the Django ORM with Datastore, take a look at https://github.com/potatolondon/djangae , which is a Datastore backend that doesn't fork Django.

Comment: Bill Prin - I'm trying to follow your advise and set up the appengine-django-skeleton app but I'm getting all kinds of problems getting it to interface with the MySQLdb.  First, it wants me to have django in a lib directory of the mysite project rather than using site-packages version.  When I use the django-skeleton specific version I get the following error      File "C:\appengine-django\lib\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by going to a MySQL solution rather than django-nonrel.  It took some time but lots on StackOverflow to help through it.